# Heroku push rejected - failed to compile - Unicode error

Tags: python, heroku, unicode

I'm new to Flask and Heroku, so to try it out, I wrote a little app that works fine when I run it locally using `foreman start`. However, when I try to `git push heroku master`, I get the following error:

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u44996/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile
(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ETnOiF-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in
/tmp/pip_build_u44996/scipy

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/
__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/
basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 70: 
ordinal not in range(128)

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

I don't really understand the error traceback here in terms of what exactly is going wrong. Is it something with scipy, or with the html templates I've made, or one of the modules? I've tried out the proposed solutions to similar questions that others have asked on stackoverflow, but I still get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And if I haven't supplied enough information above to answer the question, just let me know what you need to know and I'll gladly supply it.

Comment: It looks like this is actually a bug in Pip. [The line that's erroring](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/basecommand.py#L161) is attempting to join a bunch of log lines together using a str('\n'), which first requires converting all those log lines to strs. By default it tries to do an ascii encoding, but some log line contains a character with no ascii representation. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to figure out what's generating that unicode log-line.

Comment: @AdamK I have exactly the same error :(, any news?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line distribute==x.x.x with setuptools>=0.7 on your requirements.txt file

Works for me.